# using .each on elements loaded after DOM

Tags: jquery, live, each

I am having some issues selecting a series of links injected by JS dynamically. Basically a youtube list is built and loaded into the DOM. Now I would like to add a little bit more flare to it (without CSS animations, my challenge here, testing limits on dynamic jQuery pages really and having fun)

But it just won't select the elements loaded after the DOM and I'm tried numerous searches for a solution to no avail. Though I have had a couple bears, and it's been my birthday for 1 minute so far. Yay, happy birthday!

Here is what I'm trying and you can see it in action (rather failing) [here](http://lhc.strangled.net/ttsv1/)

```
        $('.featured-video-link').each(function(){  // featured-video-links is added after DOM too
            $(this).live({
                mouseenter: function () {
                    $(this).find('.feat-vid-title').animate({ 'backgroundColor': 'rgba(62, 132, 210, 0.8)', 'color': 'rgba(255,255,255,1.0)' }, 'slow');
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $(this).find('.feat-vid-title').animate({ 'backgroundColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', 'color': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)' }, 'slow');
                }
            });         
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following syntax and you don't need to loop,

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find('.feat-vid-title').animate({
            'backgroundColor': 'rgba(62, 132, 210, 0.8)',
            'color': 'rgba(255,255,255,1.0)'
        }, 'slow');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find('.feat-vid-title').animate({
            'backgroundColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
            'color': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)'
        }, 'slow');
    }
}, '.featured-video-link');
```

Comment: What is this voodoo sorcery! Haha thanks a lot, I look at `.on()` SO many times and didn't realize you didn't __need__ a event

Comment: @WASasquatch, then hope you will accept the answer :)

Comment: Yeah sorry I was waiting for the 15 mins and then fell asleep. :P

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to loop through each element to bind the events. Simply do like this

```
$(".featured-video-link").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('.feat-vid-title').animate({ 'backgroundColor': 'rgba(62, 132, 210, 0.8)', 'color': 'rgba(255,255,255,1.0)' }, 'slow');
    }, function() {
       $(this).find('.feat-vid-title').animate({ 'backgroundColor': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', 'color': 'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)' }, 'slow');
    }
);
```